# Load Table content from Oracle DB to Spring Bean on server run

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

1. I have a table in `Oracle11 DataBase` with two columns (`KEY(varchar2)`,`PROPERTY(varchar2)`).
2. By using Spring framework I want to load the whole content (All the rows) from the table to the Spring Bean so that instead of getting value from **DataBase** all the time I can use the Bean.
3. I used Bean class "`org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration`". It is working fine but this bean class do not have the provision to load the whole table content into it.

**PFB, my Spring-config.xml:**

```
 <bean name="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="properties" ref="commonsConfigurationFactoryBean"/>
        </bean>

<bean name="commonsConfigurationFactoryBean"
    class="org.springmodules.commons.configuration.CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean">
<constructor-arg ref="databaseConfiguration"/>
</bean>

<bean name="databaseConfiguration"
            class="org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration">
        <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" index="1" value="schema.Table_Name1"/>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" index="2"  value="KEY"/>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" index="3" value="PROPERTY"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:SYSTEM_NS:PORT:sid"/>
        <property name="username" value="xxxx"/>
        <property name="password" value="xxxx"/>
    </bean>
```

**Java Code:**

```
ApplicationContext classpathCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-config.xml");
DatabaseConfiguration dBConfig = (DatabaseConfiguration)classpathCtx.getBean("databaseConfiguration");

// To display the value in the property column by sending the value of column KEY
System.out.println(dBConfig.getProperty("Value in the KEY column"));
```

The Above code is working fine. But each time I am sending the key to `DatabaseConfiguration` it is internally making a **DataBase** call to get the property which I do not want to happen.

The whole of the above concept is all about trying to store all the data present in .properties to DB and fetching it from the DB to my Java code.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a FactoryBean that creates a properties object by reading all keys from the databaseConfiguration and copying them to the created properties object.

This properties object is then a singleton, and can be used as such in your spring config.

```
<bean name="properties" class="...ConfigurationPropertiesFactoryBean">
   <property name="configuration" ref="databaseConfiguration"/>
</bean>

public class ConfigurationPropertiesFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<Properties>
{
   private Properties props = new Properties();
   public void setConfiguration(Configuration configuration)
   {
     props.put ...
   }
   public Properties getObject()
   {
      return props;
   }
}
```

Or instead of a DatabaseConfiguration, you could use JdbcTemplate:

```
<bean name="properties" class="...DataSourcePropertiesFactoryBean">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

public class DataSourcePropertiesFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<Properties>
{
   private Properties props = new Properties();
   public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
   {
     props = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource).query("SELECT KEY, PROPERTY FROM ...", 
       new ResultSetExtractor(){
        public void Properties extractData(ResultSet rs)
        {
           props.put(...);
        }
     });
   }
   public Properties getObject()
   {
      return props;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes i do accept of creating a singleton obj in the way you have guided but in the code which you have given "<property name="configuration" ref="databaseConfiguration"/>" , we are referring to databaseConfigurationBean which dont have the provision to load all the rows i.e. all the key-value pair from the dB...                        Let us say we have 100 key-value pair in the dB. Then to load all the rows have to make 100 dB calls. I whole point is to get a way to load all the rows in one single dB call using Spring.

Comment: Added 2nd alternative doing using JdbcTemplate for a single SQL query to get all key-value pairs at once.